# React: Adding token to localStorage in loginHandler function via State hook not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-context, react-state

I've created an AuthContextProvider in my React app for login/logout-functionality:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "../api";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  token: "",
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const initialToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const [token, setToken] = useState(initialToken);

  const userIsLoggedIn = !!token;

  const loginHandler = (email, password) => {
    return axios
      .post(api.auth.login, {
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setToken(res.data.key);
        localStorage.setItem("token", token)
        // localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.key)
      });
  };

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
  };

  const contextValue = {
    token: token,
    isLoggedIn: userIsLoggedIn,
    login: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

In my loginHandler I tried to add the token received from by backend to localStorage via `localStorage.setItem("token", token)` but this always gives me `null` for the value of the token in localStorage. When I add the token via `localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.key)` I manage to get the actual token in localStorage. I don't understand why the first approach is not working, since I set `token` properly via `setToken(res.data.key)` just one line above.

Any comments would be highly appreciated

Comment: What value has `initialToken` directly after you declare it? If you just do a console.log(initialToken).

Comment: after restarting the browser it logs `null` , when I successfully login and refresh the page it logs the token string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setState()` is asynchronous. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately. If you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable, you need to pass a callback function to the `setState` function. Since in a functional component no such callback is allowed with `useState` hook, you can use the `useEffect` hook to achieve it.

[Here](https://medium.com/@sanjeewafern/perform-an-immediate-action-after-setting-state-on-a-state-variable-with-react-functional-component-e9e1526f655a) is complete explanation how to do that.